# How to add long press functionality to a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to a `UITextField` only to find that the only thing that got triggered was the `UITextField's` magnifying glass; and then when the magnifying glass disappeared the context menu appeared.

What do I have to do in order for *my* `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to be triggered instead of the default behavior?

I've already tried disabling all `UILongPressGestureRecognizers` before adding my own, as per some other SO answers, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Put a UIView on top of the textField with the same frame. Make it clear background. Add your gestures to your UIView and handle custom selections from there on. Make a tap gesture to start editing the text manually. And make a longpressgesture to do whatever you want. etc.